# Angular 2 : I am creating sticky notes board.So on click of create notes button I want to add a note everytime

Tags: angular, angular-components

So basically I want to append notes component in the main component Everytime when the create notes button is clicked from main component.

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You would need an array of `Note`in your main component. Then you can push a new instance of `Note`onto the array when the user clicks the button. You would then create a new component e. g. `NoteComponent`that renders a single `Note`instance and takes it as an `@Input`. In your main component template you would then iterate over your notes with an `*ngFor`:

```
<note [note]="note" *ngFor="let note of notes"></notes>
```

These should help you get started:

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data